# Pass Data between Multiple Applications in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, javafx, dependencies

I have a project that was started and orchestrated by someone wayyyyyy more talented than I, and I've hit a point that I can't figure how to bridge.

This is a Java/JavaFX/Spring Boot project, and NOT a Swing project. I see a lot of answers re: Swing. *Both applications* are also set up in Gradle, so *both applications* have their own separate `./gradlew bootRun` commands and are running in CentOS 7. Both applications have their own, separate, `main() methods`. I believe the original design was intended, purposefully, to remove any access to the data from the GUI, entirely, which is the reason for the separation. I'm just having a tough time finding a way to pass **necessary** data back and forth.

There are separate applications that are designed to work together.
`**Kiosk**` which houses the GUI elements and GUI-related controllers
`**Governor**` which houses an API and an APP application. The API, as of now, is helping with Source and File interfaces. The APP houses an H2 database (all stored from JSON files, but the content is irrelevant for this particular question), a User package (which houses the User data that feeds the H2 database), and a Source package (which does all the files methods)

What I want to do is:

- Get the `username` and `password`, supplied by the user at the `**Kiosk**` level, and pass that somehow into the `**Governor**`.
- Once I can pass the data, I know how to do the rest, to check against the db and verify if the user has valid credentials or not, etc.
- Once I have a boolean value (let's call id `validUser`), I want to pass that information back from the `**Governor**` to the `**Kiosk**`, and I can move on from there.

I don't have any code to copy and paste, so I am hoping that the description above is enough to point me in the right direction. I have tried googling all over for "*pass data between separate java applications*", "*separate gui and logic java application*", and everything you can think of, but I've hit a wall.

I'm happy to provide any other information you might need, and I'm not looking for anyone to write the code for me, but if you have any examples you've seen, or a concept I may not be familiar with that would help me pass this data back and forth, I would be eternally grateful!

*** Edit *** Trying to add MVP as best I can. Hopefully everything needed to answer question above can be gleaned from below.

**Kiosk/LoginController**

```java
@Component
public class LoginController extends Controller {
    @FXML
    TextField username;

    @FXML
    TextField password;

    @FXML
    Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    public void tryLogin() {
        UserServices userServices = new UserServices();
        String usernameEntered = username.textProperty().getValue();
        String passwordEntered = password.textProperty().getValue();
        userServices.validateUser(usernameEntered, passwordEntered);
        // ... other non-related methods re: tryLogin()
    }
}
```

**Kiosk/UserServices**

```java
public class UserServices {
    public boolean validateUser(String username, String password) {
        // **** How do I pass the args (username and password) to Governor?
        if (!userFound) {
            return false; // user not found, deny entry
        }
        return true; // allow entry
        }
    }
}
```

**Governor/API/FileEntry**

**Note**: This file is only a sample of an API module interacting with KIOSK--I do not understand this completely--again, doing the best I can with my limited resources; I *believe* I need to create my own API User module, but unsure how to proceed)

```java
@JsonDeserialize(as = DefaultFileEntry.class)
public interface FileEntry {
    Path getPath();
    boolean isDirectory();

    @JsonIgnore
    default Optional<String> getName() {
        if (getPath().getFileName() == null) {
            return Optional.empty();
        } else {
            return Optional.of(getPath().getFileName().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Governor/APP/UserRepository**

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRespository<User, String> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**Governor/APP/UserService**

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    // SQL methods to create database, if necessary, search, create, update, and delete users
}
```

Comment: They're actually separate *applications*? Each with their own `main(...)` method and launched independently in separate JVMs? Is that what you really mean? Anyway: *"I don't have any code to paste"*. Then create some. Write a new project from scratch (a [mre]) that demonstrates the problem (and does nothing else). All you need to do is to mimic the same problem, passing a simple value in the same way.

Comment: My recommendation though would be to abandon the code you cannot understand, drastically (and I mean massively) reduce the scope, and then write the limited functionality from scratch in a way you understand, reserving a lot of time and effort to get that done (a couple of times more time than you think you may need)  The alternative, trying to utilize, maintain and enhance the current code base is likely not feasible because there is not the skill set available to do that at the moment.

Comment: @James_D It sounds like you're beginning to get it. I can't get into the specific details, but I don't work for a "company" as it were, and my bosses, while brilliant in their own ways, can't offer help for lack of expertise of their own. But without the other senior dev to bounce questions off of and get his guidance/vision for this rewrite, (which I was completing in smaller chunks, and helped a lot to have someone critique), I have to resort to other means to help me understand. I've learned Spring, Java, JavaFX, etc. But it's a breadth vs depth scenario, and I'm drowning in the breadth.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There are several ways to for applications to share data with one another:

1. JMS, AMQ, or some other messaging system.
2. A shared database where applications poll for changes.
3. Open up a REST endpoint that each application can call to update each other. Be sure to secure with certs so outsider can't use them.

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an actual answer. (In its present form, the question doesn't really seem to be answerable.)

Comment: @Ryan These are some things I can absolutely look up. I know, for me, a lot of my problem besides being very green to this is that I don't know what I don't know. Case-in-point, I know nothing about what JMS or AMQ is, and have never used them, much less know of their existence. I'm 100% for learning new things and applying them, but if I don't know about them, I can't do anything about it. Just having the acronyms there is enough to put me on another google quest, so thank you for that! I don't know if we can use messaging systems because of certain restrictions where I work, but I'll check.

Comment: @James_D  because it is a comment.  This question is extremely broad and there is no definitive answer.  A true solution can only be determined by the people maintaining the code and the deployment environments.

Comment: OK, but if it is a comment, post a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @WillDutcher JMS (Java Messaging System) is a very old system for passing messages.  AMQ is an Apache project https://activemq.apache.org/.  It's a very robust system for passing messages between system, both internal and external.

Comment: @James_D I posted an answer broad enough to match the question and to give the OP a direction.